# Default Apache, PHP and MySql on Mac 10.6.8

Tags: php, mysql, apache, macos, osx-snow-leopard

May I know which Apache, PHP and MySql I am running if I decided to used other server solution/ packages (such as MAMP) than the one preinstalled on my Mac? If It possible to have multiple Apache, PHP and MySql running at the same time? Or would it be better if I just remove all the Apple's default installation?

Currently I have Apache (2.2.17), PHP (5.3.4) preinstalled on my Mac OS X 10.6.8. I don't see if I have any Mysql installed. May I know how to make connection to between Apache, PHP and mySql. I know there are connected through "socket" but how am I connect them If I have multiple version of the same thing installed?

Sorry for the long questions.

Thanks & Regards,
Jeno

Comment: Please keep it to one question per post.

Comment: What do you mean by "M[a]y I know which [...] I am running"?

Comment: The question is still unclear. Are you asking how to check which binary is running as a given server (e.g. a web server running on port 80)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run multiple installs of Apache as long as each listens on different ports. You can run multiple MySQL installs as long as each listens on different ports & sockets and has a different [data directory](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-install-db.html#option_mysql_install_db_datadir). You can even run the same install of either as multiple server instances; there's no real difference between the two scenarios.

Don't remove Apple's install of Apache or PHP. Instead, disable (or, in the case of Apache, don't enable) them.

MySQL isn't part of the default system software.

Apache generally doesn't interact with MySQL. PHP itself also doesn't interact with MySQL; it's PHP scripts that do, and that's a matter of using the correct connection information when the script creates the connection (e.g. when creating a PDO object). If there are multiple SQL servers running, simply use the appropriate port number or socket path.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll leave the default Apple's alone.

I've decided to use the all-in-one MAMP soft-of solution so that I have an graphical interface to configure all my ports and socket. It make life easier for a novice like me, but guess I will run into problem again if I need to install extra apache module.